# Create a picture frame type border

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I am trying to create a page that is contained in what can be visualized as a picture frame type border/frame as shown here:
[image]

So far I've found three ways to do it none of which truly fit my needs, I need this frame to be responsive so that it fills the whole screen and keeps roughly the same ratio (don't want the frame panels to get stretched too thin).
I can make each wall using CSS roughly like:

```
#left-wall {
    border-left: 120px solid black;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 10%;
    width: 0px;
}
```

with an inside element just a tad smaller and white to leave only the border remaining, but that is a lot of markup and not responsive.

There is SVG

```
<svg height="400" width="500">
    <polygon points="0,0 100,100 100,300 0,400" style="fill:white;stroke:gray;stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

Which is much simpler code, but again not responsive.

Then there is also the canvas option but if I wanted it to be full screen and responsive I'd have to redraw every window resize which seems over complicated.

So is there a simple responsive way to a frame like shown above?

Comment: Do you have to support IE8 and less?

Comment: Nope just main/current browsers would be fine

Comment: Add a viewBox to the SVG e.g. viewBox="0 0 400 500"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have to support IE8 and less, you can use one pseudo-element and `background-image` to achieve the frame effect and also have it responsive with minimal code.

The inner box is generated using the pseudo element and the angled parts on all sides are achieved using angled `linear-gradient` background images. The `linear-gradient` images have the same dimensions as the space left for the frame on all 4 sides. In this snippet it is 50px space on all four sides and so the dimensions of the `linear-gradient` image is 50px X 50px.

```css
.frame {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 48.5%, gray 48.5%, gray 51.5%, transparent 51.5%), linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 48.5%, gray 48.5%, gray 51.5%, transparent 51.5%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 48.5%, gray 48.5%, gray 51.5%, transparent 51.5%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 48.5%, gray 48.5%, gray 51.5%, transparent 51.5%);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  background-position: top left, bottom right, top right, bottom left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 50px;
}
.frame:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  top: 48px;
  left: 48px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">Some text</div>
```